# Error: NG04002 after converting from Angular to Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I just created new Angular app, and converted it to Angular Universal. When I run the project using **npm run dev:ssr**, I'm getting following error in the terminal:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002
Error: NG04002
    at Recognizer.noMatchError (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:2343326)
    at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:2343696
    at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:514891
    at OperatorSubscriber2._this._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:503575)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
    at resolvePromise (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:733524)
    at resolvePromise (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:732497)
    at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:735394
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:719497)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:912531)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:719387)
    at Zone3.runTask (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:712485)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:722734) {
  rejection: RuntimeError: NG04002
      at Recognizer.noMatchError (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:2343326)
      at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:2343696
      at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:514891
      at OperatorSubscriber2._this._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:503575)
      at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
      at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
      at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
      at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
      at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
      at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784) {
    code: 4002
  },
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
    __zone_symbol__state: 0,
    __zone_symbol__value: RuntimeError: NG04002
        at Recognizer.noMatchError (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:2343326)
        at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:2343696
        at D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:514891
        at OperatorSubscriber2._this._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:503575)
        at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
        at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
        at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
        at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784)
        at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457318)
        at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (D:\MyProjects\PROJECTNAME\dist\PROJECTNAME\server\main.js:1:457784) {
      code: 4002
    }
  },
  zone: <ref *1> Zone3 {
    _parent: Zone3 {
      _parent: null,
      _name: '<root>',
      _properties: {},
      _zoneDelegate: [_ZoneDelegate]
    },
    _name: 'angular',
    _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
    _zoneDelegate: <ref *2> _ZoneDelegate {
      _taskCounts: [Object],
      zone: [Circular *1],
      _parentDelegate: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _forkZS: null,
      _forkDlgt: null,
      _forkCurrZone: null,
      _interceptZS: null,
      _interceptDlgt: null,
      _interceptCurrZone: null,
      _invokeZS: [Object],
      _invokeDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _invokeCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _handleErrorZS: [Object],
      _handleErrorDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
      _scheduleTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
      _invokeTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
      _cancelTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
      _hasTaskZS: [Object],
      _hasTaskDlgt: [_ZoneDelegate],
      _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular *2],
      _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1]
    }
  },
  task: ZoneTask {
    _zone: <ref *1> Zone3 {
      _parent: [Zone3],
      _name: 'angular',
      _properties: [Object],
      _zoneDelegate: [_ZoneDelegate]
    },
    runCount: 0,
    _zoneDelegates: null,
    _state: 'notScheduled',
    type: 'microTask',
    source: 'Promise.then',
    data: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
      __zone_symbol__state: 0,
      __zone_symbol__value: [RuntimeError]
    },
    scheduleFn: undefined,
    cancelFn: undefined,
    callback: [Function (anonymous)],
    invoke: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

The project itself does compile successfully, and it works, but this error remains in the terminal.

I've tried finding solution on Google and here, but all solutions offered were closely related to different problems than the one I have.

Comment: Did you already search for `NG04002`? It means "Cannot match any routes"

Answer (score 1):

It seams you just have a problem in a routerLink value with a route that does not exist.

This error happens often when you put links not starting from root because you are more likely to make a mistake in route.

try changing routes from:

```
routerLink="destination"
```

to

```
routerLink="/your_root/parent/.../destination"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The occurrence was minor, but it irritated me. What I have found is [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50787).

It seems that I have some urls with `()`. You can check if you have some.